# Writing my first blackberry app

Tags: c++, iphone, blackberry, java-me

I am contemplating writing my first BlackBerry app. I am fundamentally a C/C++ programmer, not Java. Can anyone provide some guidelines on the quickest route, i.e. shallowest learning curve, to writing a BlackBerry app?

Any resources/links would be useful.

As an aside:

In an ideal world, I would like to write once and deploy for both BlackBerry and the iPhone, but since I am targetting largely business people, I think BlackBerry should be my target - right?

Is it possible to write once and deploy on BOTH iPhone and BlackBerry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skyeagle,

With a C/C++ background, I'd suggest you start on the iPhone. Not only will you be more comfortable with the language but it's only a limited range of devices to worry about - in comparison with the BlackBerry market which varies vastly in form factor and ability (and is of course in Java).

However, if you were sure about doing BlackBerry, the main BlackBerry site is probably the place to start, along with the support forum - oh, and StackOverflow :) The JDK comes with plenty of examples which will cover the basics too.

I also suggest you do a little searching on here - getting started with BlackBerry development has already been covered a few times and probably hasn't changed that much over the last little while.

Final note - if you want to be on the bleeding edge of development, what about looking to develop for the PlayBook, soon to be RIM's latest offering?

Stuart

Answer (score 1):

C++ and C programmers can easily jump into Java and Actionscript. 

I would suggest you to write application in Flash using actionsscript. 
As you are a beginner, AS3 will be a good start as it provides easy constructs and API for UI programming.

Moreover, doing AS3, you can easily port it over to Android too. 
If you are very particular to develop for both Blackberry and iPhone, then try using web technologies. Both phones support web technologies and create web apps.

These apps are also very easy to create and can even run on Adnroid with minor changes. My suggestion is to use your progrmming basics and try to venture into all possible languages to get a breadth.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your requirements but you could use something like [mosync](http://www.mosync.com/)

Comment: Looks interesting - but the potential deal breaker is that its GPLd. Does that mean that any apps I write with it will be GPLd?.

Comment: No I think there is a commercial license you can get